# Replace geometries from a list in sf

Tags: r, list, r-sf

Suppose I have the following `sf` data frame:

```
library(sf)

nrows <- 10
geometry = st_sfc(lapply(1:nrows, function(x) st_geometrycollection()))
df <- st_sf(id = 1:nrows, geometry = geometry)
```

And I also have the following list:

```
mylist = list('2'=st_point(c(-73,42)), '3'=NA)
```

I want to replace the geometry from the second observation with the point in the list.  I had thought about doing the following:

```
st_geometry(df[names(mylist),]) <- st_sfc(mylist)
```

But this throws an error:

> "Error in vapply(lst, class, rep(NA_character_, 3)) :    values must
>   be length 3,  but FUN(X[[2]]) result is length 1"

I found the following workaround by first eliminating the NA values:

```
condition <- mylist[!is.na(mylist)]
st_geometry(df[names(condition),]) <- st_sfc(condition)
```

Is there a better way to do this? Can I force the NA elements in `mylist` to be empty points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not working because in.

```
mylist = list('2'=st_point(c(-73,42)), '3'= NA)
```

`3` is not a POINT but a logical, which (probably) can not be "forced" in any way into a `sf` object.

You can circumvent this by substituting your the NA elements of `mylyst` to empty POINTS beforehand. For example:

```
mylist[[which(is.na(mylist))]]  <- st_point()
st_geometry(df[names(mylist),]) <- st_sfc(mylist)
```

, giving:

```
> df
Simple feature collection with 10 features and 1 field (with 10 geometries empty)
geometry type:  GEOMETRY
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -73 ymin: 42 xmax: -73 ymax: 42
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    NA
   id                 geometry
1   1 GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY
2   2           POINT (-73 42)
3   3              POINT EMPTY
4   4 GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY
5   5 GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY
6   6 GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY
7   7 GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY
8   8 GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY
9   9 GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY
10 10 GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY
```

HTH.

Comment: In this example, the list had only one NA; how would I do it if it had more than one NA element? The double bracket throws an error in this case.

Comment: `na_rows <- which(is.na(mylist))` ; `for (row in na_rows) st_geometry(df[row,]) <- st_sfc(st_point())`